# How to delete from select in same table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a rather complicated query that I've been using for a long time in SQLite. It starts like this:

```
delete FROM 
   verbal_sets 
WHERE verbal_sets.verbal_set_id IN( 
   SELECT 
       F.verbal_set_id 
   FROM verbal_sets AS F WHERE Exists( 
       SELECT 
         knowledge_id, phrase_id,first_entity_text, second_entity_text,verbal_relation_text, Count(verbal_set_id) 
       FROM
        (...)
```

I'm now creating a MySQL supported version of the same software but MySQl doesn't like this query. It returns the error:

```
[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'verbal_sets' for update in FROM clause
```

I have no experience with MySQL specifics. Can anyone point me what must be done with this query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/45494/) and [**many** others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bmysql%5d%20%2b%22you%20can%27t%20specify%20target%20table%22%20%2b%22for%20update%20in%22%20%2bdelete).

Comment: Can you post the MySQL version of the query if it's any different?

Comment: @ChrisC - The MySQL query is what I'm trying to build. This is the SQLite query.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you,

```
delete FROM 
   verbal_sets 
WHERE verbal_set_id IN( 
   SELECT * 
    From( 
       SELECT knowledge_id, 
              phrase_id,
              first_entity_text, 
              second_entity_text, 
              verbal_relation_text, 
              Count(verbal_set_id) 
       FROM  verbal_sets
       ) as c
)
```

Comment: Actually, I was dealing with the same problem and i got this solution.

Answer (score -1):

Just skip a few lines:

```
DELETE FROM 
   verbal_sets 
WHERE Exists( 
       SELECT 
         knowledge_id, phrase_id,first_entity_text, second_entity_text,verbal_relation_text, Count(verbal_set_id) 
       FROM
```